# calling an MVC controller from c# class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

how to call the controller action method from model c# class method.

```
if (dic_fare.Count == 0)
{

}

public ActionResult Index()
{

}
```

Comment: why do you need to call the controller from model?

Comment: Can you tell us more details, what is your purpose, what do you want to do?

Comment: `new HomeController().Index();` but if you are doing that you've got a **serious** design issue somewhere...

Comment: @Adriani6 how would you provide `HttpContext` and other framework specific dependencies while initiating controller yourself?

Comment: A little missing details in the question. From which context does the caller-code run? web? class library? Note that any code in C # is class.
And what is meant to "call", do you want the output to build a web response?

Comment: @Aarif That's not the point in my comment as it wasn't explicitly asked in the question. He might have other dependencies he expects in the controller himself.. the point of my comment is that there's something wrong with his design if he's doing that.

Comment: @Adriani6 controllers are the responsibility of the framework to instantiate and should never be instantiated manually and what you've done is basic C# class instantiation that I hope one should know before start working on `ASP.NET`

Comment: @Aarif That just made no sense specifically the part where you hope that one shouldn't know how to instantiate a class in c#... but that's besides the point of you ignoring what I said previously as I said I agree with you and my comment is not encouraging him to do it but to notice that he has a **serious design problem if he is doing it**.

Comment: @@hi there ...this is my question ............I create a method in model db class  . so i want that when any error in this method then call the login action method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking the wrong question.

Controllers are meant to be invoked by HTTP requests through the ASP.NET MVC pipeline, not directly from your code.

If you *really want to*, but you shouldn't, you can just create an instance of the controller (`var controller = new YourController(/* dependencies */)`) and call the desired action method on it (`var result = controller.Index()`). But then chances are that you're missing various dependencies (`ControllerContext`, `HttpRequest`) and that you can't really parse the response.

Instead refactor your code. Move the code you want to another class, and call that class from your controller - and from the code you now want to call the controller from.

Comment: there ...this is my question ............I create a method in model db class . so i want that when any error in this method then call the Acountcontroller login action method.                            thanks for answering...

Comment: Sorry but that makes no sense to me. Why do you want to do that, what should happen from the user's perspective?

Comment: Dear ..actually i create a database connect class and i call it into controller action method .this is the reason that i want when user enter fields and i check the user authenticated or not . this code in database class and when any error in this class then i want to open the login form....

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you mean. When any exception occurs, you want to show a login form? Why?

Answer (score 2):

When you want this, your design is off.

To call the Action you would first have to instantiate a Controller and that expects to run in a HttpContext and has all sorts of other expectations.

The thing to do is to factor out the business logic you want to use and put that in a separate class, for instance in a `\Services`folder in your project.